# Unable to upload image on EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I developed an application in Django. I deploy this on amazon EC2 instances and I also used AWS PostgreSQL RDS. This application contains a report form. This report form also contains an Image Field. When I submit the form from my laptop then report creating successfully and my image store in the EC2 instance and also display in the feed page.

But when I submit the form from a mobile phone then again report created successfully and my image is also stored in EC2 instance but it is not displayed in the feed page. When I check error in Nginx Server then I got the following error:

```html
2018/08/20 19:34:37 [error] 4498#4498: *89 open() "/home/ubuntu/media/153476127499997915256.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 103.201.
```

I don't know much about AWS.

Comment: Give the permission to root access

Comment: To whom and how?

Comment: I deploy this application from my Aws root account

Comment: Also check the folder permission

Comment: How? please tell me. I am new to Aws and I want to remove bug.

Comment: Hey @RajaRamachanfran please check this now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955531/unexceptional-behaviour-of-my-django-application-image-hosting-on-aws

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't an AWS question. It's a hosting/server question.

The error you're receiving is caused by a lack of permissions for the user the server runs as. You'll need to find out what user your Django server runs as, then ensure that the directory: `/home/ubuntu/media/` is writeable by your Django server.

You can change ownership using the command `chown {user}:{group} {path}`, or use `chmod` to adjust the permissions such that the user can write the file.

Comment: Please check this now and reply thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955531/unexceptional-behaviour-of-my-django-application-image-hosting-on-aws